# Stepformwizard is not getting hidden. Overflowing on right of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Am not very expert in jquery and stepformwizard. Am working on code written by someone else. The issue is the multistepformwizard fieldset is used and the next step should be loaded only when Next button is clicked. But  currently both of the steps are visible on the screen with extra horizontal scrollbar. I dont want the step 2 form to be visible. Here is the html and jquery code.

```
<div class="ztab-sec ztab-desbrd bksrvsec bksecrv2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">                 
                <form  action="<?php echo base_url()?>service/service_request" method="POST" id="wizard_example_6" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ownerArr[0]['email_id']; ?>" name="email_id">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ownerArr[0]['phone']; ?>" name="mobile">
                    <fieldset>
                            <legend>Basic information about your car</legend>

                                <div class="row bkmargin">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Vehicle Brand</label>
                                        <select id="u_car_id" class="form-control" name="car_id" required>
                                            <option selected disabled value="">Select a Car</option>
                                            <?php foreach ($cars as $car_details) : ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $car_details['user_car_id']; ?>"><?php echo $car_details['makesTitle']; ?>   (<?php echo $car_details['modelsTitle']; ?>) <?php echo $car_details['car_reg_no']; ?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Variants</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="variant" placeholder="Variants" required data-parsley-group="block0"  id="variant" readonly pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]*$">
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Transmission</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Transmission" name="transmission" readonly required data-parsley-group="block0" id="transmission" pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]*$">
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <legend class="clearfix">Select service for your car?  <a href="#"  class="car-link pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" >Add New Car</a></legend>                                   
                            <div class="row bkmargin">  
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group besrvx">
                                        <input id="option-one" name="service_type" value="1" class="styled-radio " type="radio" data-parsley-group="block0" required data-required-message="Please check one service">
                                        <label class="srvlabel" id="1" for="option-one"><strong>Basic Service: </strong> 
                                            <span class="srvspa">3 months or 5000 kms (whichever is earlier)</span>                                        
                                        </label>                    
                                    </div>                                          
                                </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
                            <legend>Vehicle picked up address  </legend>
                            <div class="row bkmargin">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Address</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="user_add_id" name="pick_id">
                                            <option selected disabled>Select Address</option>
                                            <?php $i=1; foreach ($address as $user_details) : ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $user_details['add_id'] ?>"> Address <?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
                                            <option id="neww" class="neww" value="neww">Select new Address</option>
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Address Type</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="add_type" name="add_type" disabled>
                                            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Address Type</option>
                                            <option value="Home">Home Address</option>
                                            <option value="Office">Office Address</option>
                                            <option value="Other">Other Address</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>  
<div class="row bkmargin">  
                                <noscript>
                                    <input class="nocsript-finish-btn sf-right nocsript-sf-btn" type="submit" value="submit"/>
                                </noscript>                             
                                </div>          

</fieldset>
        </form>
```

I have skipped some part as its a long form. I want the second fieldset should only be visible when user clicks on next button

here is the jquery

```
 w6 = $("#wizard_example_6").stepFormWizard({
        onNext: function(b, a) {
            return $("#wizard_example_6").parsley().validate("block" + b)
        },
        onFinish: function(b) {
            return $("#wizard_example_6").parsley().validate()
        }
    });
    var d = window.location.hash.match(/^#step-(\d+)/),
        c = 0;
    null !== d && (c = d[1] - 1);
    w7 = $("#wizard_example_7").stepFormWizard({
        startStep: c,
        onNext: function(b, a) {
            window.location.hash = "#step-" + (b + 2)
        },
        onPrev: function(b, a) {
            window.location.hash = "#step-" + b
        },
        onFinish: function(b) {
            window.location.hash = "#form-sended"
        }
    })
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    prepare_example();
    $("pre code").each(function(c, b) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(b)
    });
    var d = $(location).attr("search").match(/t=([a-z]+)/);
    "undefined" != typeof d && null != d ? ($(".sf-wizard").parent().removeClass("sf-sea").addClass("sf-" + d[1]), $(".bt-" + d[1]).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info")) : $(".bt-sea").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info")
});
```

Please help me with this. I have tried using  but no luck also changed css display:none inplace of block but couldnt resolve the issue.